# PHP script mucks up copyright

Tags: php

I have written a PHP script that goes through and changes the HTML generated by Visual Page.  (I know - it is a REALLY old program - but I like it.)  Anyway, in each of these HTML web pages I'm working with I put in:

{copyright}

Where I want the copyright to show up.  I did the following loop:

```
foreach( $file as $k1=>$v1 ){
   if( preg_match("/\{copyright\}/i", $v1) ){
      $file[$k1] = preg_replace( "/\{copyright\}/i", $copyright, $v1 );
      }
   }
```

This DID NOT WORK.  I would echo out the $file[$k1] before and after the IF statement so I could see what was going on and PHP just wouldn't change the {copyright} to the copyright.  The variable $copyright had something similar to:

```
<tr><td>Copyright 2007-NOW MyCompany.  All rights reserved.</td></tr>
```

Now - here is the freaky thing:  I put a BREAK after it did the preg_replace - and - it worked.  So just changing the above to

```
foreach( $file as $k1=>$v1 ){
    if( preg_match("/\{copyright\}/i", $v1) ){
        $file[$k1] = preg_replace( "/\{copyright\}/i", $copyright, $v1 );
        break;
        }
    }
```

Made it work.  Does anyone have ANY kind of an idea why?  I'm completely stumped by this.

Note: I thought I'd post what I had gotten the HTML down to.

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Test</title>
</head>
<body>
<table border='1' cellspacing='0' cellpadding='0'><tbody>
<tr><td>This is a test</td></tr>
{copyright}
</tbody></table>
</body>
</html>
```

That is what I boiled my test case down to.

Also note : I did get this to work.  Don't know why I had to put in a BREAK statement and I put it in on a whim.  My thinking went "Maybe there is something that is making it re-evaluate the string after the change?  Let me try putting in a break statement."  I did and - it worked.  But I have no idea WHY it worked.

Comment: And now just remove this break and all works still :) I think, bug was fixed anywhere else.

Comment: First, there is no need to first check if there is a match and then do a replace. Just do the replace, and if there is no match the replace will just leave the string the way it was. Second, unless it must be case insensitive, there is no need to use regex for this. An ordinary `str_replace` would work just as well, since you are only matching a fixed string.

Comment: To : Anders - str_replace would not find it.
@vp_arth - Nope.  This frustrated me for hours.  That was why I isolated it.  To try to figure out what was going on.

Comment: @Anders - I forgot to answer your other comment: Doing the test is faster than trying to replace the string on every line.

Comment: You should debug it step-by-step... Try to add `$file[$k1].=' ok...';` to each loop iteration..  You obviously lie us.. There is nothing to fail with posted code. Your actual code is other.

Comment: There was no lying at all.  As posted below - it turned out to be a bad RAM issue.  I've replaced the RAM chips in my laptop and now I'm not getting what I was getting.  I can only assume that the laptop overheated (I sometimes leave it running while I go to work) or the RAM just started going bad and this was the symptom I got.  I also had gotten a couple blue screens of death before this but the system seemed to be ok after a reboot.  Obviously not.  You really should not say someone is lying unless they really are lying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe I'm missing something here but it doesn't seem like you need any regex's here. The `str_replace` function, http://php.net/str_replace, should work fine for this.

Example:

```
$string = "<html>
<head>
<title>Test</title>
</head>
<body>
<table border='1' cellspacing='0' cellpadding='0'><tbody>
<tr><td>This is a test</td></tr>
{copyright}
</tbody></table>
</body>
</html>";
$copyright = '<tr><td>Copyright 2007-NOW MyCompany.  All rights reserved.</td></tr>';
echo str_replace('{copyright}', $copyright, $string);
```

Output:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Test</title>
</head>
<body>
<table border='1' cellspacing='0' cellpadding='0'><tbody>
<tr><td>This is a test</td></tr>
<tr><td>Copyright 2007-NOW MyCompany.  All rights reserved.</td></tr>
</tbody></table>
</body>
</html>
```

Demo: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/f53b1a96f270e52392303d7dfb7c327372747d0b

Update per comment:

```
$string = "<html>
<head>
<title>Test</title>
</head>
<body>
<table border='1' cellspacing='0' cellpadding='0'><tbody>
<tr><td>This is a test</td></tr>
{copyright}
</tbody></table>
</body>
</html>";
$copyright = '<tr><td>Copyright 2007-NOW MyCompany.  All rights reserved.</td></tr>';
foreach(explode("\n", $string) as $line) {
    echo str_replace('{copyright}', $copyright, $line) . "\n";
}
```

Output:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Test</title>
</head>
<body>
<table border='1' cellspacing='0' cellpadding='0'><tbody>
<tr><td>This is a test</td></tr>
<tr><td>Copyright 2007-NOW MyCompany.  All rights reserved.</td></tr>
</tbody></table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Explode the $string and use a foreach to go through the lines. See original post.

Comment: Explode on what, newline? Okay, ran test, works as stated in this answer still.

Comment: For unknown reasons str_replace would not find the "{copyright}".  Thus the preg_match with the "i" option.  I probably should have tried the stristr() function though.  Yes.  Newline.

Comment: Maybe I should try re-installing PHP?  Could have a bad spot developing on the disk or maybe I've clobbered something.  That might account for this weird stuff happening although I would have thought that PHP just wouldn't work then.

Comment: Run something against the sandbox page and your machine. Make sure versions are the same.

Comment: Done.  Got some weirdness.

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Possible weirdness?
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

</html>></table>t 2007-NOW MyCompany.  All rights reserved.</td></tr>


I put the code into the sandbox and it works correctly there.  So it is >MY< machine that has a problem.

Sandbox: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/f34f57f6521cc6eebcc704b7c127974c0403834d

Comment: And you ran on the same PHP versions and same encoding?

Comment: My PHP version is 5.4.41.  Closest version they have is 5.4.34.  Same encoding.  Also - I had the wrong link.  Never used sandbox before.  Corrected the link.

Comment: Not sure what is happening or what that link is showing now. This is sounding like a different issue though than this question was.

Comment: Yeah.  I'm beginning to wonder if I have RAM or drive problems.  That would not be good.  :-(

Answer (score 0):

Although I am not yet sure exactly what is wrong - with the help of chris85 I no longer believe it is a PHP problem but instead is probably a hardware problem.

Chris posted to the PHP sandbox what I said I was using and it worked without a flaw.  When I tried it ON the PHP sandbox (which means it used the sandbox's PHP interpreter) - it also worked without a problem.

Then I modified the program so it did the same thing but in two other ways.  Thus, test #1 was just the single string, test #2 was the exploded string, and test #3 echoed out each individual string as it was modified.

On >MY< machine, the third method caused unexpected output to be generated.  As stated though, the PHP sandbox computer did NOT have anything strange happen to it.  Thus, this means that there is a hardware problem with my computer and not with PHP.

Sandbox link: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/f34f57f6521cc6eebcc704b7c127974c0403834d

This question can now be closed.